# How can I receive custom protocol deep links from Edge on HoloLens 2 into Unity 2019 UWP app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, microsoft-edge, hololens

I am trying to implement a sketchfab oauth2. On the HoloLens 2, Edge opens and provide the standard confirmation (once logged in to sketchfab) taking me to the redirect page. So far, so good. The problem arises when my redirect page attempts to open a custom protocol (that should be registered by Unity). The browser detects the custom protocol and prompts me to look for an application in the Store, but does not prompt me to open my application.

If I install the Unity UWP app on a non-AR device, it works as expected. Is there something funny about how HoloLens 2 Edge Browser handles these?

I have followed this guide from Unity (https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/enabling-deep-linking.html), so the deeplinkmgr is there and the custom protocol is listed in the relevant place in Unity's player settings.

Building for UWP with Unity 2019.4.5, D3D project, Min SDK 17134. The HoloLens OS is up-to-date.

I have found a few pages from 2016/7 that offer some ideas, but they seem to be out of date or related to XAML applications only.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SketchFab oauth2, but if you need a way to launch a flat browser window directly inside your unity app, please refer this code:[LaunchUri.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_development/Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/HandTracking/Scripts/LaunchUri.cs).

Comment: For example, have a look at [launch browser example](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/5047) which shows the behavior in the [HandInteractionExamples](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_development/Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/HandTracking/Scenes/HandInteractionExamples.unity) scene.